# What Platform Use for the Site?

Tags: wordpress, web, platform

I want to make a website more likely like the site https://www.homely.com.au/ with is a real estate site. I can see that some pages have WordPress Structure but the homepage doesn't have that WordPress imprint and I do wonder what 3rd Party System do they use?

Thanks if you answer my question.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This web is using ReactJS. To get the details there are two ways

1. Easy: Use https://www.wappalyzer.com/ or https://builtwith.com/
2. Advanced : Go to Developer tool of the browser and get the details. Specifically for this web you can see the worker processes, this is one of the hint that they are using any JS framework.